# Problem in creating own log in azure using functions

Tags: azure

Can anyone give information ( to be precise an example code) on how to create own logs that should be given to azure application insights using soome azure trigger function.

Thanks in Advance, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use Logger and Iloggger, we can use Log.Warning or Log.information for creating your own log :***

***Function.cs:***

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class MainFunction 
    {
    [FunctionName("MainFunction")]
            public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
            {     
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
                _logger.LogInformation($" Hey SAKR THIS IS FOR YOU");
       
        _logger.LogInformation($" SAKR  COMPLETED YOUR WORK");
                }}
}
```

***host.json :***

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Can u please say me how to check the logs in portal?